# porque no aparece la vista de diseño web en visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, .net

estoy creando un sitio web en visual studio pero al querer ver el diseño no aparece solo el codigo html y nada mas, le doy click en Diseño y se queda ahi, en el codigo, que puedo hacer?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: probaste reiniciar?? fijate que la ventana no este minimizada o achicada para algun lado..

Comment: Seguramente debes ampliarlo, solo pon tu mouse en el borde y alarga hacia arriba.